# OpenId4java logout

Tags: openid, yahoo, logout

We are developed the app engine application. In that we used the openid4java to login from the google/yahoo. Its working for login where as not for logout. The google/yahoo sessions are not cleared form this openid4java.

When i searched i came to know that, this is not possible form openid. Please suggest on this is there any other way to logout from global session(google/yahoo).

Thanks in advance.

Thanks,
Govind.

Answer (score 0):

OpenID specification doesn't have a Single Logout profile. Therefor most of the OpenID Providers would not support this unless if they have implemented it in their own way. Try clearing cookies, that might work.

Answer (score 0):

**Google logout:**

```
function googleLogout() {
    window.open( 'https://www.google.com/accounts/Logout' );
    alert( 'logged out from google.' );
}
```

**Yahoo logout:**

```
function yahooLogout() {
    window.open( 'https://login.yahoo.com/config/login?logout=1' );
    alert( 'logged out from yahoo' );
}
```

**Bonus - Facebook logout:**

```
function facebookLogout() {
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
        if( response.status === 'connected' ) {
            logoutFromFB();
        }
        else {
            alert( 'already logged out from facebook');
        }
    }, true);
}

function logoutFromFB() {
    FB.logout(function(response) {
        alert( 'logged out from facebook' );
    });
}
```